# Apple not currently accepting applications built with this version of the sdk (Xcode 4.2, iOS SDK 4.3)

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I recognize that there are 2000 other SO posts on this question, but none I have seen are specific to Xcode 4.2 and iOS SDK 4.3. I am wondering if anyone knows of a setting that I am perhaps missing.

I have set the Base SDK in my project and target Build Settings panels to iOS 4.3, all to no avail. FWIW it seems like the build warnings I am getting are all SDK 5.0 related deprecations.

Are there any other project/target settings I am missing, or is this a lost cause building 4.3  apps in Xcode 4.2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Xcode 4.2 has not been officially released. It's still in beta. So you cannot submit an app built with it. Use Xcode 4.0.1 (Snow Leopard) or 4.1 (Lion). [4.1 for Snow Leopard is also available, if you can download it...]

Comment: Been trying to dl 4.1 for SL but keep getting errors. Haven't seen a link for 4.0.1 though...

Comment: The download error on 4.1 for SL is wide-spread, apparently, according to chatter in Apple's dev forums. I am hoping that is resolved quickly. If you go to connect.apple.com (log in as needed), you might find a 4.0.1 dmg to download.

Comment: Looks like I have an old copy lying around of xcode 3.2.5 with 4.2 sdk, I'll try my luck there. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I've got Xcode 4.1 for SL and I was able to submit apps yesterday, but I can no longer today. I wonder what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that Xcode 4.2 is still in beta. You cannot submit apps with this version. Downgrade back to Xcode 4.1, that supports building apps for iOS 4.3, too. Xcode 4.2 is really only for beta testing iOS 5 apps.

Answer (score 0):

Apple will not be accepting any apps built with Xcode 4.2 until it is out of beta.